# How to display a list of items from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question requires that by defining a function called `print_room_items(room)` I should take a room as an input and display a list of items found in this room. If there are no items in the room, nothing is printed.

Here are 2 of the rooms:

```
room_reception = {
    "name": "Reception",
    "description": '768',
    "exits": {"south": "Admins", "east": "Tutor", "west": "Parking"},
    "items": [item_biscuits, item_handbook]
}
room_tutor = {
    "name": "your personal tutor's office",
    "description": '890',
    "exits": {"west": "Reception"},
    "items": []
}
```

The code I came up with is:

```
def print_room_items(room):
    room_item_01 = room['items'][0]['name']
    room_item_02 = room['items'][1]['name']
    print(room_item_01)
    print(room_item_02)

print_room_items(rooms["Reception"])
```

Such code doesn't look particularly elegant. On top of that I do get an error when I try to run the code for a room without any items instead of no output. In this case, the Tutor room.

Comment: Just a heads up with making a function like that, what if there are 100s of items in the room, not just 2 or none? Excellent use case for `for ... in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the items:

```
def print_room_items(room):
    for item in room['items']:
        print(item['name'])
```

If you want to print the items in one line, separated by commas, you can use the `str.join` method with a generator expression instead:

```
def print_room_items(room):
    print(', '.join(item['name'] for item in room['items']))
```

Comment: What happens if `items` and/or `name` of `items` does not exist?

Comment: Then fix the corrupted data. If the data model is clearly defined then this should not be an issue.

Comment: The solution does work, but I ran into a problem which is my fault due to the lack of description. The solution actually does ask to print them on the same line with a line break following the print. 

So for reception, I'd ideally need to print the statement "There is a pack of biscuits, a student handbook here.". Since i'm running a loop though i end up printing them on 2 different lines. I gave print(item['name'], end = ' ') a go, but the sentence ends with a period and is separated by a comma plus the line break (\n) disrupts it, Any idea how i could go about this?

Comment: @user15428 I see. I've updated my answer with a solution to print the item names on the same line, separated by commas.

Comment: Alright i just realized that i'm supposed to call a previous function to do this process and I'm still confused on how to do it. I'm supposed to take the code and use it to produce a comma separated list :

def list_of_items(items):
    
    new_list = []
    for key in items:
        new_list.append(key['name'])
    
    print(', '.join(new_list))
        
   
    
list_of_items([item_pen, item_handbook])

Comment: @user15428 No.. you should use either a `for` loop or `join`, but not both. Remove the `for` loop and `print(', '.join(item['name'] for item in items))`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
def print_room_items(room):
    for item in room ['items']:
        print(item)
```

Or, if what you need to print is "item ['name']":

```
def print_room_items(room):
    for item in room ['items']:
        print(item['name'])
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest way. List comps are nice, but not necessarily for beginners to wrap their head around.

Comment: can try `item.get('name', 'none')`, if no value return a default one

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do `join`:

```
def print_room_items(room):
    print('\n'.join([item['name'] for item in room['items']]))
```

Btw if want to condition the existence (meaning if `items` and/or `name` of `items` does not exist?):

```
def print_room_items(room):
    try:
        print('\n'.join([item['name'] for item in room['items']]))
    except:
        print('error')
```

Or list comprehension print:

```
def print_room_items(room):
    [print(item['name']) for item in room['items']]
```

Btw if want to condition the existence (meaning if `items` and/or `name` of `items` does not exist?):

```
def print_room_items(room):
    try:
        [print(item['name']) for item in room['items']]
    except:
        print('error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
def print_room_items(room):
    [print(item) for item in room["items"]]
```

If there are no items, it will not throw an error and simply return nothing.

However in the current code, 'item_biscuits' and 'item_handbook' are undefined. If you can show us an example of one of these items, perhaps we can better help.

Comment: Isn't that i mine?